# Laravel 5.4 won't validate JSON

Tags: json, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and trying to validate JSON in my POST request however the validator fails stating that the JSON isn't valid, even though it is. I'm assuming I'm not understanding the validation rules correctly and my implementation is wrong, rather than a bug or something else.

I have a simple POST endpoint which has both the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers set to `application/json`.

In my POST request (testing using Postman) I'm supplying RAW data.

```
{
    "only_this_key": { "one": "two" }
}
```

In my controller method I have the following:

```
// I'm using intersect to remove any other parameters that may have been supplied as this endpoint only requires one
$requestData = $request->intersect(['only_this_key']);

$messages = [
    'only_this_key.required' => 'The :attribute is required',
    'only_this_key.json' => 'The :attribute field must be valid JSON',
];

$validator = \Validator::make($requestData, [
    'only_this_key' => 'required|json',
], $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return new APIErrorValidationResponse($request, $validator);
}

return response()->json(['all good' => 'here']);
```

The error I get back is ***The inventory field must be valid JSON*** even though it is!

Passing in the raw data using Postman

```
{
    "only-this-key": {
        "item-one": "one",
        "item-two": "two",
        "item-three": "three"
    },
    "not": "wanted"
}
```

When I use `dd($request->all());` within the method

```
array:2 [
  "what-i-want" => array:3 [
    "item-one" => "one"
    "item-two" => "two"
    "item-three" => "three"
  ]
  "not" => "wanted"
]
```

Comment: Do you really need to send this as Raw data?

Comment: Yes, I only want one field (the body) as such, not separate parameters

Comment: Can you run `dd($request->all())` first thing in your controller and post what it shows you?

Comment: For some reason Laravel is turning the value into a PHP array - most likely it is calling `json_decode` behind the scenes. Therefore it is not valid JSON by the time it reaches the validator - it is an array. I have no idea why I did not see the same behavior in my test (maybe it's even a difference in Postman settings). Of course you could call `json_encode` on the value and it should pass, but I am perplexed as to *why* you are getting this behavior...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how Laravel is interpreting the raw data in the request. If you run `dd($request->all())` in your controller you will see this output:

```
array:1 [
  "{"only_this_key":{"one":"two"}}" => ""
]
```

Your entire JSON string is getting set as a key with a value of an empty string. If you absolutely *must* send it as raw data, then you're going to have to grab that key value and save it to an array with the key that you want. This should work (instead of the `intersect` line).

```
$requestData = ['only_this_key' => key($request->all())];
```

Alternatively, you can just send the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded` with your entire JSON string as the only value for one key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that isn't what happens, `$request->all()` does contain the data as I'd expect.

Comment: Mike, strange I have your exact same setup. I am using Laravel 5.2 - maybe there is some difference between the versions?

Comment: I guess that _could_ be it, although I doubt it, as I don't think anything like that has changed.